# error code : 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.loginid,t1.`company_name`,t1.`FA_Name`,t1.`Lot`,t1.`PurchasePrice` FROM test_report t1
WHERE PurchasePrice IN (SELECT t1.loginid,t1.`company_name`,t1.`FA_Name`,t1.`Lot`,MAX(t1.`PurchasePrice`) FROM test_report t1 GROUP BY lot)
ORDER BY lot;
```

Giving error Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Trying to fetch the appropriate loginid , company name , fa_name by grouping the lot and get max purchaseprice.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect can only have one value in select clause:

```
SELECT t1.loginid,t1.`company_name`,t1.`FA_Name`,t1.`Lot`,t1.`PurchasePrice` FROM test_report t1
WHERE PurchasePrice IN (SELECT MAX(t1.`PurchasePrice`) FROM test_report t1 GROUP BY lot)
ORDER BY lot;
```

Comment: Jens  Thanks for reply but the above query remain in execute state only. It is not ending. Any help will be appreciated.